# How to save the global variable value in Django and how to get that saved value if I reloads the page?

Tags: python, django

I have one webpage which track user tasks every day.
I want to freeze a date by that the user cannot be able to edit their data before that date.
This is done by an admin.So I declare a global variable(flag) in views.py and when the admin freezing the date that value is assigned to True.
But when a user logged in that value is not changed.
How can I do this?

Comment: why not save this flag into the cache/redis/database?

Comment: I don't want to use a database for this. I didn't get the concept of cache you mentioned above.

Comment: How about save it in a file, and loads the data from the file before your functions' return